# Ubuntu 18.04: disable screensaver

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, screensaver

I am trying to disable the screensaver in Ubuntu 18.04, that is I don't want ever the screen to "go black" after some time. This is different from disabling auto-lock etc. I guess I am confused between related concepts such as idle, suspending and auto-lock.

I saw various parameters online, and set them all to the values that should disable any screensaver, lock screen, idle etc... but I am still getting a black screen after some time.

Which further parameter should I adjust? I have so far:

```
$gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
$gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
$gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean mot to blank the screen?

Comment: @Matifou `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0` this command will make auto blanking to stop.. but your Q is disabling screensaver which is different.

Comment: Yes, @Graham, I guess I mean avoid to blank the screen (also blank means also white, but blank screen means black one).

Comment: @PRATAP ok, I'll try that. Maybe I am just confused between these concepts (see edited question), maybe the answer could clarify these concepts?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings → Power → Blank Screen.

[image]

It's not an obvious place for the option but it does allow you to set different time options before the screen blanks.